# Structural binding and type of variables

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to ask a question about structural binding and how the variables get their types.
Here is the code I compile.

```
struct T {
  explicit T(int a = 1) {
    a_ = a;
    std::cout << "Default" << std::endl;
  }
  T(const T& t) {
    a_ = t.a_;
    std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
  }
  int a_;
};

int main() {

  std::tuple<bool, T> bi{true, T(1)};
  std::cout << "START" << std::endl;
  auto& [b, i] = bi;
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), T>::value);
  std::cout << i.a_ << std::endl;
  i.a_++;
  std::cout << i.a_ << std::endl;
  std::cout << (&i == &get<1>(bi)) << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and the result is:

```
Default
Copy
START
1
2
1
```

As you can see the variable `i` actually refers to `get<1>(bi)`.
However, the type of the variable `i` is `T` since `std::is_same<decltype(i), T>::value`.
Could you please explain why structural binding works this way?
I have read about it in the book "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide"
and the authors state that the variable `i` must have type `std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<bool, T> >::type&&`. I don't understand why `decltype(i)` is just `T`.

Comment: Does the book really say that `i` should be an rvalue reference? I'd understand if you expected an lvalue reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype` is funny that way. Its specification contains a special clause for structured bindings

> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4) For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is
>   defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as
>     given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;
> - ...

So while each structured binding is indeed a reference into the tuple, `decltype` reports the type of the referent. Likely since structured bindings are meant to feel like regular named variables.