# Why does structured binding introduce variables as values, not references?

Tags: c++, structured-bindings

I'm learning about structured binding declarations. My understanding was that in `auto& [x, y] = expr;` variables `x` and `y` are introduced of types "reference to `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`" (for `i=0, 1` and `E` is the type of the invisible variable `e`). Moreover, these variables are initialized with `get<i>(e)`.

So, if I use `auto&` and `get<>` returns a value (not a reference), it should not compile, as you cannot bind an lvalue to a temporary. However, the following example builds for me in some versions of GCC, Clang, and Visual Studio:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
    template<std::size_t i>
    int get() { return 123; }
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct tuple_size<Foo> : integral_constant<size_t, 1> {};
    template<std::size_t i> struct tuple_element<i, Foo> { using type = int; };
}

int main() {
    Foo f;
    auto& [x] = f;
    x++;
}
```

Moreover, [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/31134459) clearly shows that clang expands the structured binding to:

```
Foo f = Foo();
Foo & __f17 = f;
std::tuple_element<0, Foo>::type x = __f17.get<0>();
x++;
```

Here, it declares `x` not as a reference, but as a value. Why is that?

I expected lvalue references and compilation error: `e` (`__f17` in the example above) is an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `auto&` does not apply to the structured bindings. It is applied to the underlying entity that refers to the structure. In your cppinsights snippet, that would be `__f17`.

If you were to use `auto [x]` instead, the snippet would expand to something like this

```
Foo f = Foo();
Foo __f17 = f; // Difference here
std::tuple_element<0, Foo>::type x = __f17.get<0>();
x++;
```

The bindings themselves are always a sort of reference into an underlying object. The cppinsights code doesn't accurately represent that however. The relevant passages in the C++ standard say this

> **[dcl.struct.bind]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.struct.bind) Otherwise, if the qualified-id `std​::​tuple_­size<E>` names a
>   complete type, the expression `std​::​tuple_­size<E>​::​value` shall
>   be a well-formed integral constant expression and the number of
>   elements in the identifier-list shall be equal to the value of that
>   expression. The unqualified-id `get` is looked up in the scope of `E` by
>   class member access lookup, and if that finds at least one
>   declaration, the initializer is `e.get<i>()`. Otherwise, the
>   initializer is `get<i>(e)`, where get is looked up in the associated
>   namespaces. In either case, `get<i>` is interpreted as a template-id.
>   [ Note: Ordinary unqualified lookup is not performed.  — end note ] In
>   either case, `e` is an lvalue if the type of the entity `e` is an lvalue
>   reference and an xvalue otherwise. Given the type `Ti` designated by
>   `std​::​tuple_­element<i, E>​::​type`, each `vi` is a variable of type
>   “reference to `Ti`” initialized with the initializer, where the
>   reference is an lvalue reference if the initializer is an lvalue and
>   an rvalue reference otherwise; the referenced type is `Ti`.

Comment: While this makes sence, doesn't the quoted text state that `vi` must be a reference (to something in this underlying `e`, whenever it is a reference or not)?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry - It does. Like I mentioned, CPP insights does not correctly represent that.

Comment: If bindings are references into an underlying object, how can they be bound to a temporary object? They should be lvalue-references because `__f17` is a lvalue.

Comment: The lvalue-ness of `__f17 ` has little to do with this. The initializer for the binding is  `__f17.get<0>()`, that's an rvalue, so the reference type is an rvalue reference (clearly stated in the text). As far as binding references to temporaries, are you at all familiar with [reference lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)? That's how.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, thanks! Yet I stil ldon't get something: I have built a different sample that returns references from `get` so I should get references (and it works from asserts I have placed), yet decltype reports I don't have those: https://godbolt.org/z/4ekbud

Comment: @LapshinDmitry - It's a quirk of `decltype` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830650/structural-binding-and-type-of-variables

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh wow, thanks. Why would it do it, though? Pretend it's actually a "tuple element" in the first place?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry - I can only speculate. My guess is that it's to make structured bindings feel more like regular variables instead of references in disguise, since their declarations look more or less like regular objects.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking that "the initializer" in "where the reference is an lvalue reference if the initializer is an lvalue and an rvalue reference otherwise" refers to the initializer of `e` somewhy.