# Why can't I unpack entries of std::map into references?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I have noticed that unpacking keys and values from `std::map` does not give me references. I am assuming that individual entries in `std::map` is stored as a pair of const key and value.

What works:

- Manually taking `.second` of pair from `std::map` into reference.
- Unpacking a pair made using `std::make_pair` into references.
- Taking references from result of `std::views::values`

What doesn't work:

- Directly unpacking map entries in for loop into references
- Unpacking map entry obtained from iterator into references

Why do above two not work? Attached is a sample source code, and deduced types from the IDE. The compiler does result in same error messages with the insertions.

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> data;

    for (const auto& kv : data) {
        auto& v = kv.second;
        auto& [a, b] = kv;
        static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>);
    }

    for (const auto& v : data | std::views::values)
        static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>);

    for (const auto& [k, v] : data)
        static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>);  // error

    {
        auto& kv = *data.begin();
        auto& [k, v] = kv;
        static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>);  // error
    }

    {
        auto kv = std::make_pair(3, 5);
        auto& k = kv.first;
        auto& v = kv.second;
        static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: deduced types]

Comment: Can you add the exact compiler error messages? Intellisense error squiggles don't have the final say here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `std::map`. It's just that the names in a structured binding are not references. Related/dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340567/why-does-structured-binding-introduce-variables-as-values-not-references

Comment: @alterigel It's two static assertion failed on squiggled lines.

Comment: @cigien I can't believe I forgot to check what would result from `auto& [k2, v2] = kv;` in the last block. This does result in two non-references too.

Comment: The question is why you need a reference here. Each structured binding introduces *one* anonymous variable, and if you use `auto&`, it is a reference. `k` and `v` are its members. You can change `v` and it will reflect back to `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a reference. However, there is a special rule that `decltype` on a structured binding does (from [[dcl.type.decltype]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.1)):

> - if `E` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(E)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;

And the *referenced* types for a map's pair (which is a `pair<Key const, Value>`) are just `Key const` and `Value`, never any kind of reference.

Comment: *It is a reference.* If `v` is a reference, then `std::is_reference_v<decltype(v)>` should be true.

Comment: [CWG2313](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2313) changed them to be magic lvalues for the objects bound to the anonymous references.

Comment: @DavisHerring I feel like that's a distinction without a meaningful different for their usability - they behave like references. It's also pretty unfortunate I think that `decltype(v)` just lies here, because there's no way to forward a structured binding.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It is a reference. As my answer says, `decltype(v)` just doesn't give you a reference type, that doesn't change the fact it behaves in every other way like the reference you'd expect.

Comment: @Barry _they behave like references_ What does it mean: to behave like a reference?